# Lazily loaded module in Angular 4 errors with "Component X is not part of any NgModule"

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular4-router

I have an app with loads of modules. It works perfectly. I want to make one module lazy load as it is not often hit by normal users.

So, I change the route for LazyModule to use `loadChildren`, the main app still loads ok, but when I try and hit one of the child routes of LazyModule, it gives me this error:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component HomeComponent is not
>   part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your
>   module.

HomeComponent is not used in LazyModule. It is part of a different module, call it MainModule.

MainModule and LazyModule are both imported and exported to/from ComponentsModule which then gets imported into the app.module.

There is also SharedModule which is imported to all the other modules mentioned.

> So my questions:
>
> - Why does LazyModule try to load components in MainModule when it has absolutely no dependencies on it?
> - Why does it work with normal routing, but not with lazy loading?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Modules are here:

**LazyModule**

```
import ...;

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/lazy-page/1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '1',
        component: LazyPage1Component
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forChild(routes),
      SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
      LazyPage1Component
  ]
})
export class LazyModule { }
```

**MainModule**

```
import ...;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
      HomeComponent
  ],
  exports: [
      HomeComponent
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

**ComponentsModule**

```
import ...;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    MainModule,
    LazyModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    SharedModule,
    MainModule,
    LazyModule
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

**AppModule**

```
import ...;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppRoutingModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
},
{
    path: 'lazy-page',
    loadChildren: './components/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule',
},
```

EDIT: I found a hack to get around it for now, but I really want a proper solution. The hack is just to import every single module in my app into LazyModule as well as AppModule. This is a terrible solution, because the whole idea of having a lazy-loaded module is to decouple it from the rest of the app as it is separate. I don't want to import everything twice, and nor should I need to since none of the modules imported are ever used or referenced inside LazyModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Dmitry Grinko I re-organised my router, which led me to find that I had randomly imported app-routing.module into a different module.

The solution was to remove this extra import, and it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this **AppRoutingModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
{
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './path/to/main.module#MainModule',
        }
    ]
},
{
    path: 'lazy-page',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: './components/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule',
        }
    ]
}
```

Your **app.component**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**MainRoutingModule**

```
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
},
```

And this is your **LazyModule routes**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '1',
        component: LazyPage1Component
    }
];
```

And **remove ComponentModule**

Hope it helps

Comment: HomeComponent is exported from MainModule into the AppModule, so this is not the issue. Moreover, it has no problem loading the portion of the main app, only the lazy-loaded route.

Comment: On the other point, i don't think that's it either - ComponentModule is not imported to LazyModule, so LazyModule should not care what is going on in there.

Comment: If you would give me more meaningful names of your modules, maybe I help you more

Comment: How much more meaningful do you need than Main, Shared, and Lazy?

Comment: ComponentsModule is just a wrapper to pass all modules into the AppModule. I only added this to facilitate my hack (added as an edit in the question) - the issue persisted before this though so it is not related to ComponentsModule

Comment: I added LazyModule routes as well

Comment: Thanks for this - it wasn't the solution, but it helped me get better error handling and a better organised router, which led me to find that I had randomly imported app-routing.module into a different module.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I just want to comment that lazy loaded modules need not be imported into your app module as your are adding it to Component module and importing to app module.

Lazy loaded modules can remain as independent module from app and will be loaded when the route needs activation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and similar to what @Dmitry suggested I simply removed all routes from my AppRoutingModule and left the root + the lazy loaded module route. I got a different error message like @DoubleA mentions in the comments.

[image: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice]

In the end I was importing AppRoutingModule in my SharedModule which at the same time was also being imported in the lazy loaded module. I'll have to refactor to avoid AppRoutingModule.